# Send an event from html form to a jsx component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I am new to React,
My question is:
I have a button (Btn) in html form and a react input text (TXT) component; I want to make the button clicked on the "oninput" event of the txt.

this is the component jsx file:

```
(function(app){

    function component(){

        var Date = React.createClass({
            getValue: function() {
                var el = $(this.getDOMNode());
                var input = el[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
                return $(input).val();
            },
            componentDidMount: function() {
                var el = $(this.getDOMNode());
                var element = el[0].childNodes[1];
                $(element).datetimepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    startView: 'decade',
                    minView: 'month',
                    isRTL: false,
                    //pickTime: false,
                    pickerPosition:"bottom-right"
                });
            },
            render: function() {
                return (<div className="form-group" style={{display: '-webkit-box'}}>
                    <label>{this.props.title}</label>
                    <div className="input-group date ">
                        <input type="text" name={this.props.name} style={{paddingRight: 0,
                            fontSize: 12}}  readOnly className="form-control"  className={this.props.class}/>
                        <span className="input-group-btn">
                            <button className="btn default date-set" type="button"><i className="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>);
            }
        });

        function create(elementId,props){
            return React.render(<Date {...props} />, document.getElementById(elementId));
        }

        return {
            create:create
        };
    }
    app.component('dateComponent',component);

})(beirutHubBaseApp);
```

The button is in html file; this button is a search button made by jquery datatable so it has to be in the datatable.

this is the controller:

```
jd = dateComponent.create('jd',
                {
                    title:"",
                    name:"filter_joinDate",
                    class:"form-control form-filter datepicker"
                });
```

So how to make this event?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of having

```
var el = $(this.getDOMNode());
var element = el[0].childNodes[1];
```

You should use refs, this is what they are for, see http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html .

Second, your getValue function is not at all in the spirit of React. Either you also use refs and then you can get your input value through `this.refs.input.value` or you use a state to store the value.

Concerning your problem :

- if you want to react to the click on the button to trigger something in the text field, you should add the listener in the componentDidMount, like this :

componentDidMount:

```
var c = this
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
    // do something here, with c instead of this to refer to the component
})
```

Do not forget to also implement the componentWillUnmount to clear the listener.

- If you want to trigger something in the button in reaction to an input (which I believe is what you are looking for), you should add a listener to the input like this `onInput={this.handleInput}` and have a handleInput this way :

handleInput:

```
handleInput: function() {
    $("#mybutton").doSomethingWithJquery()
},
```

Comment: Dear Mijamo,
thank you but It didn't work noting that I tried to debug by putting in onInput event console.log("something"); It prints only when I load the screen